# Elasticsearch search api to get total hit count?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case:

1. I need to use _search API to fetch whole bunch of records in a paginated way.
2. But at the same time, I would want to get the total hit number in the same _search API call.

Example:
The pagination number is 50, that is, I want to fetch result in a 50 batch manner. At the same time, I want to get the total hit number, let's say 5000 for each search call.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this possible? get total hit number as the result of a _search API call?
2. Would the total hit number be impacted due to the pagination?

Comment: You can use the count API, then paginate over the batch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

Comment: But that means I need to call 2 APIs right? one _search and one _count. I'm wondering if I can solve this issue in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can get total hit in search API with adding `track_total_hits=true` option.

`GET localhost:9200/_search?pretty&track_total_hits=true`

2. if you are using search API with `from=X&size=50` for pagination, yes it is possible that the number of docs change during of pagination. but it depends of refresh interval. you can increase the refresh interval. there is another solution for this problem. Pit API.
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html

also `from=X&size=50` with you have limit for pagination(I think you can only fetch 10000 docs) you could increase this limitation. or use scroll API.

Answer (score 0):

Image from Search API [ES-DOCs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html).. You can use hits -> total.
[image]